# Extracting data from the relational table to the AppServiceProvider

Tags: laravel

I have two tables GROUPS and PAGES in relationship One Group to many Pages. The tables are linked together using group_id (in pages table). The current code allows me to display the names of all groups, but not to display pages assigned to a particular group.

Model Group:

```
class Group extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'navbar_id',
    ];

     public function pages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Page::class);   
    }
}
```

Model Page:

```
class Page extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'group_id'
    ];    
    public function groups()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Group::class, 'group_id');
    }
```

ForeignKey:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('pages', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->integer('group_id')->unsigned()->change();
            $table->foreign('group_id','pages_group_id_foreign')->references('id')->on('groups');
        });
    }
```

AppServiceProvider:

```
view()->composer('*', function($view){
            $view->with('topbar', Group::where('visible',1)->with(['pages'])->get());
});
```

and fragment of View:

```
@foreach($topbar as $group)
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
   <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">{{ $group->title }}</a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      @foreach($group->pages() as $page)
      <li class="">
         <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">{{ $page->title }}</a>
      </li>
      @endforeach
   </ul>
</li>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your eager loading code and relationship is set up correctly

The error is in the Blade view, you're trying to access the `pages()` relationship instance on the `group` instead of the collection `pages`

Call the collection, not the relationship

```
@foreach($group->pages as $page)
```